# Adding Horizon and Sky to a Pokemon Go-like Map?

Tags: cartography, style, mapbox, augmented-reality

I am trying to create a map similar to the Pokemon GO map. I have used mapbox studio to create a sytle which I am pretty happy with.

However I am wondering how to get a horizon and a sky on this? Not sure where to start with this.

Comment: you would need to use a 3D projection (globe), mapbox is 2d. try cesium https://github.com/openlayers/ol3-cesium